# Honeywell RTH7600 does not responsd

Tags: air-conditioning, thermostat

Just installed new Honeywell RTH7600.  All wires are correct and the unit displays fine.  The issue is that heater and AC do not turn on at all.  I even put the fan to ON instead of AUTO and that does not turn on either.  not sure what the issue is.

THe unit will display "Heat on" or "Cool on" to indicate that something should be happening.  I hear a click from the unit, but nothing actually happens.

So far I ihave tried power cycling at the circuit breaker.  But im thinking about first re-seating all the wires and second reinstalling the old unit to make sure that still works and that my ac/heater didn't just go out at the same time somehow.

Comment: Do you have a heat pump? If so, is the thermostat set up to work with a heat pump? Did you check the furnace/air handler to make sure it has power? Do you have a multimeter, and know how to use it?

Comment: As far as I know its a gas furnance.  dont have multimeter.  I read online that after reset the circuit breaker it can sometimes takes up to 30 minutes for the units to reset and start working again....so im gonna wait it out.  Also read to check the fuses. I Just re-seated all the wires.

Comment: Without a multimeter, you're not going to much troubleshooting.

Comment: I got a multimeter, what do I test?  I put the old unit back on and still  nothing is working anymore.  It was working great before i decided to swap out the thermostat this morning.  I took a picture of all the wires and their locations beforehand, so i know exactly where everything is supposed to go.

Comment: after reading some issues others have had ive seen mentioned of having to turn off breakers for indoor and outdoor units?  supposedly the outside breaker isn't enough and i was supposed to turn something off inside as well?  If i was supposed too...i didn't and don't know wwhere that is

Comment: If you swapped out the thermostats with the power on, you could have shorted out the transformer. Best case is a blown fuse, worst case is a blown transformer. Do you have a `C` wire at the thermostat? If so, there test AC voltage (VAC) between `R` and `C`.  You should get between 24 and 30 volts.

Comment: @Tester101 The multimeter read 15.2V.  I definitely turned off the outside breaker, so if I did swap it out with the power still on how would that of happened?  is there another breaker or switch i would have had to power off other than outside breaker?  Since nothing is working (AC,Heater,FAN), it would seem there is some central area where all those devices connect that is having the issue.

Comment: The breaker for the gas furnace should have been off. That's the central location, where all the control wiring passes through.

Comment: THere wasn't a breaker on the outside box for the furnace, just 2 labeled AC.  so would the furnace breaker be located next the furnace?  Perhaps the breaker just got tripped.  You mentioned a possible blown fuse, i'm guessing the fuse im looking for would be by the furnace as well?

Comment: The furnace breaker should be in the main panel, or there will be a servicemen switch near the furnace. If a fuse is blown, it will be on the control board inside the furnace.

Comment: ok im gonna go check for the switch and fuse.  THere are 2 breakers that I am not sure what they are for: FAU and Service Disconnect.  would any of those be used for the furnace?

Comment: SOB i just saw that FAU is for forced air unit...that was my breaker i was supposed to turn off.  Gonna try to power cycle it and then hope for just a fuse on the furnace...

Comment: Service Disconnect will probably turn everything off, not sure what FAU stands for.

Comment: @Tester101 issue is resolved, fuse on the board blew out.  If you put up an answer I will accept it.  thanks for all your help, I appreciate it...and especially my wife!!  lol

Comment: I'll send you the bill.  Glad I could help point you in the right direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you swapped out the thermostats with the power on, you could have shorted out the transformer. Best case is a blown fuse, worst case is a blown transformer. Do you have a `C` wire at the thermostat? If so, test AC voltage (VAC) between `R` and `C`.  You should get between 24 and 30 volts.

The furnace breaker should be in the main panel, or there will be a servicemen switch near the furnace. If a fuse is blown, it will be on the control board inside the furnace.

Comment: FYI for anyone with similar issue, the Furnace breaker was labeled as "FAU" on the main panel.